# Subscript in annotate in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a novice question:
with this code section, I would like to put the `1` of `VT1` as subscript.

```
[...]
  annotate("text", x=VT1PPO_CAD-2, y=40,   ##or bp_CAD if we use absVO2%
           label=paste0("VT1: ", round(VT1PPO_CAD, 0), "%"), angle=90, size = 4) +
[...]
```

I have tried this but it does not work.

```
label=paste0(expression(paste("V", T[1], ": ")), round(VT1PPO_CAD, 0), "%")
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a complete example including  the code, inputs and library statement so that others can actually run it using copy and paste from the question.  See the top of the [tag:r] tag page for posting guidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67857985/680068 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9723239/680068

Comment: This two posts are for superscript of R squared. Mine is for subscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `substitute`:

```r
VT1PPO_CAD <- 96.32

plot(1:5,
     main = substitute(paste(VT[1],": ", value1, "%"),
                       list(value1 = round(VT1PPO_CAD, 0))
                       )
     )
```

[image]

Or `ggplot2` (as per your tag):

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1:5) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = substitute(paste(VT[1],": ", value1, "%"),
                         list(value1 = round(VT1PPO_CAD, 0))
                          )
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue with your attempted solution is that that your *entire* label needs to be an unevaluated expression if you want R to format it properly. Your code attempts to use the unevaluated expression as part of a character string (the outer `paste0` call converts the arguments to strings). This does not work.

So instead you need to invert the logic: you need to create an unevaluated expression, and you need to interpolate your variable (`VT1PPO_CAD`) *into* that expression (after rounding).

The `expression` function does not allow interpolating values<sup>1</sup>. To interpolate (= insert evaluated) subexpressions, you need to use another solution. Several exist, but my favourite way in base R is the [`bquote`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bquote.html) function.

Furthermore, there’s no need to split and/or quote `V` and `T`; just put them adjacent:

```
bquote(paste(VT[1], ": ", .(round(VT1PPO_CAD, 0)), "%"))
```

`bquote` accepts an expression and evaluates sub-expressions that are wrapped in `.(…)` before inserting the result of the evaluation into the surrounding expression.

---

<sup>1</sup> In general the `expression` function is completely useless, I have no idea why it even exists; as far as I can tell it’s 100% redundant with `quote`. The answer is probably [“for compatibility with S”](https://twitter.com/WhyDoesR).